# Time of life of a solution of a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Can you help me in showing that there exist $r >0$ such that for every $\|(x_0,y_0)) \| \leqslant r$ the solution of the Cauchy Problem :
\begin{align*}
x'+x&=y^2\\y'+y&=x^2 \end{align*} with the boundary $(x(0),y(0))=(x_0,y_0)$ is definined on $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e the solution lives infinitely).

Thank you.

PS. I tried to find a "bounded" energy and I didn't succeed, but I want to show that $(x',y')$ is locally bounded.

Comment: You can use the lyapunov function $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ to find an attraction basin of the critical point $(0,0)$.